# What's the standard for XML-RPC fault codes?

Tags: xml-rpc

In the process of writing a pingback handler for my website, I noticed that the [XML-RPC specification](http://www.xmlrpc.com/spec) doesn't say anything about what fault codes should be defined and what they should mean. So the question is, is there a commonly accepted standard for fault codes that specifies this information? Which fault codes are defined and what do they mean? Both for XML-RPC in general, and for specific applications (like pingback)?

I think I know an answer to this but I'd like to get the community's input on it (and I think it's good reference material to have on SO).

Answer (score 12):

http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net/specs/rfc.fault_codes.php seem to be widely accepted.

Answer (score 2):

XML-RPC doesn't define fault codes because that's an application level definition. XML-RPC is just a carriage format: It specifies data, it doesn't specify what's in the data. Fault codes are generally server-specific.

That said, general uses of XML-RPC may have some standard fault codes, and you'd do well to look them up because I'd imagine there are some for something as widespread as pingbacks.

Comment: I know fault codes are application-level, but the point is to get a reference for the standard ones.

Comment: The point is there ARE no standard ones: only ones defined for each application. For pingback specific faultcodes, look at http://hixie.ch/specs/pingback/pingback-1.0#TOC3 but there are no generic, standard fault codes. Fault codes are wholly application specific.

Answer (score 0):

There is no global list of fault codes. It is up to the server implementer, or higher-level standards to specify fault codes.

http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/spec.html